# Многоуровневое меню на JS и jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Когда то на одном проекте, второпях написал код для очень запутанной многоуровневой навигации с кучей подменю. 
Конкретно этот кусок отвечал за отображение следующего уровня меню с содержанием соответствующим нажатой кнопке. То есть при нажатии на кнопку с одним из классов ["**.1st**", "**.2nd**", "**.3rd**"], элемент в другом блоке, например **div.1st_list** получает класс **.active**, но если **.2nd** уже **.2nd.active**, то сначала у **.2nd.active** удаляется **.active** и уже потом **div.1st_list** получает **.active**.
То есть одновременно активным может быть только один элемент.

```
       $(function() {
   Sub_menus = [".1st", ".2nd", ".3rd"]

   for (var i = 0; i < Sub_menus.length; i++) {
       (function(sub_item) {
           $("." + sub_item + "_item").click(function() {
              if ($("." + sub_item + "_list.active")[0]) {
                   $(".gne_snd .dynamic_inner>div").removeClass("active");
                   $(".gne_snd").removeClass("active");
                   $(this).removeClass("for_anim");
               } else if ($(".gne_snd.active")[0]) {
                   $(".gne_snd .dynamic_inner>div").removeClass("active");
                   $("." + sub_item + "_list").toggleClass("active");
               } else {
                   $(".gne_snd").toggleClass("active");
                   $("." + sub_item + "_list").toggleClass("active");
               }
           });
       })(Sub_menus[i]);
   }});
```

Поскольку и JS, и jQuery знаю очень поверхностно, написал как мог.

И собственно, что хочу узнать.

Есть ли более элегантные, может быть эффективные, решения для подобных задач? Как еще можно написать код для такой задачи?

Answer (score -1):

Вот более универсальнее код. Написал на скорую руку поэтому есть возможность сделать его еще более лучшим. Все достаточно просто. Если нужно новый выпадающий список просто добавляете классы и все готово.
Html и Css на CodePen
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MGNmzY

```
$(() => {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').hover(function () {
        $('.dropdown-menu--sub').removeClass('active');
        $(this).siblings('.dropdown-menu').addClass('active');
        setTimeout(() => {
           $(this).siblings('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('active');
       }, 5000)
   });
});
```